Advanced Audit Policy configuration using PowerShell
I created a GPO to enable advanced audit policies and Security settings.
Related policy settings
I need to edit and enable the settings using PowerShell.
What are the related registry keys?
How can I edit using PowerShell?
Could you help me please?
Thanks in advance!

The audit settings and some security settings aren't registry values. They are stored in the secedit.sdb database.
If you need to change the advanced audit settings from the command prompt, you may use auditpol.exe.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/auditpol-get
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/auditpol-set
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/secedit

I couldn't see a gpo setting related. When I enable an audit via auditpol, it enables for all users/computers in AD?

@recmad: tell us what setting that you need that you don't see. Auditpol changes the settings on the host where it is run.

I want to enable audits for all users/computers but I don't want to run the command on all computers because of the number. That's why I want to accomplish using GPO. If any there is any other way, I am open.

@recmad: tell us why you aren't using Group Policy but instead need another deployment mechanism?

No, I already created a GPO for this, but I don't know how to edit this GPO using powershell to enable mentioned audits.

No. It isn't editable in PowerShell.

Thank you, sadly.
